# Free restful api to practice with?

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

Im sort of new to network programming. I want to use libraries like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), etc to write practice applications so I can learn how to post and get responses from an endpoint. Are there any free restful services i can use to practice with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256103/some-good-examples-of-restful-web-apis

Also popular web applications like Facebook, Google, Twitter all have REST APIs